# Retrieving time from mysql database by spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, java-time

I have database column with time datatype and I am trying to get that time to do some operations, if that column having more than 23:59:59 hour I'm getting error.

Service class:

```
LocalTime taskMaxTime = repository.findbytaskid(timeSheet.getTaskId());

// here instead of LocalTime I have tried String , java.time.Duration , 
   java.sql.Time and org.apache.tomcat.jni.Time but didn't worked
```

Repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT total_hours FROM tasks WHERE id=:taskId", nativeQuery = true)
LocalTime findbytaskid(@Param("taskId") Integer taskId);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
2021-09-25 19:05:32.625  WARN 116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: 
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S10092021-09-25 19:05:32.625 ERROR 116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The value '30:00:00' is an invalid TIME value. 
JDBC Time objects represent a wall-clock time and not a duration as MySQL treats them. If you 
are treating this type as a duration, consider retrieving this value as a string and dealing 
with it according to your requirements.

  2021-09-25 19:05:32.649 ERROR 116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]. 
  [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with 
  path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is 
  org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

  com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataReadException: The value '30:00:00' is an invalid TIME value. 
  JDBC Time objects represent a wall-clock time and not a duration as MySQL treats them. If 
  you are treating this type as a duration, consider retrieving this value as a string and 
  dealing with it according to your requirements.
```

[error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RG5w.png)

I've been stuck on this for so many days... can anyone provide a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like there's a problem during "deserialization" of your time object. Do you also create database records using Spring Data JPA, I guess you're using Spring Data JPA right? What column definition (SQL Type) do you use? `TIME`? `30:00:00` is obvouisly no valid time...

Comment: Isn’t the message in your screen shot pretty accurate and helpful? *If you are treating this type as a duration, consider retrieving this value as a string and and dealing with it according to your requirements.*

Comment: @0x1C1B yes i'm using Spring Data JPA And using time datatype for  column , How can i overcome this problem

Comment: @OleV.V. tried to retriew as string but getting same error , can you give an example how  to do that.

Comment: I don’t have Spring Boot, so sorry, I can’t (my question was meant as that, a question). Are you saying that you tried to declare `String findbytaskid(@Param("taskId") Integer taskId);` and got *If you are treating this type as a duration, consider retrieving this value as a string and and dealing with it according to your requirements.*? I find that funny.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are retrieving a DURATION into a TIME object. That doesn't work if the DURATION is greater than 24 hours.
One of the work around could be you, can retrieve it as a String and do the further processing like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CONCAT(total_hours, '') total_hours FROM tasks WHERE id=:taskId", nativeQuery = true)
String findbytaskid(@Param("taskId") Integer taskId);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned in error message that time in mysql database is invalid format So that is why when your application returns time from database application is unable to recognize valid time format.
Also check data type corresponding to this time in the database.

Comment: can you please suggest me what type of datatype should be used ??

Comment: You  know there's not 30 I a 24 day, right? How will you interpret hour 30?

Comment: Yes i know that but i'm asing for a solution!!!  for entering 24 + hours in database